# Unable to display two tables (side by side) inside a panel

Tags: python, rich

Using Python (version: 3.10.6) and the [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) (version: 13.3.1) package, I'm attempting to display two tables side by side inside a panel, like this:

```py
from rich.panel import Panel
from rich.table import Table
from rich.console import Console

console = Console()

table1 = Table()

table1.add_column("a")
table1.add_column("b")

table1.add_row("a", "b")
table1.add_row("a", "b")

table2 = Table()

table2.add_column("c")
table2.add_column("d")

table2.add_row("c",  "d")
table2.add_row("c",  "d")

panel = Panel.fit(
    [table1, table2], 
    title="My Panel",
    border_style="red",
    title_align="left",
    padding=(1, 2),
)

console.print(panel)
```

This code is producing the following Traceback:

```py
  File "/home/linux/ToolkitExtraction (copy 1)/table_in_panel.py", line 33, in <module>
    console.print(panel)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1694, in print
    extend(render(renderable, render_options))
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1326, in render
    for render_output in iter_render:
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/panel.py", line 204, in __rich_console__
    else console.measure(
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1278, in measure
    measurement = Measurement.get(self, options or self.options, renderable)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/measure.py", line 109, in get
    get_console_width(console, options)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/padding.py", line 132, in __rich_measure__
    measure_min, measure_max = Measurement.get(console, options, self.renderable)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rich/measure.py", line 119, in get
    raise errors.NotRenderableError(
rich.errors.NotRenderableError: Unable to get render width for [<rich.table.Table object at 0x7f562c1c2470>, <rich.table.Table object at 0x7f562c0411e0>]; a str, Segment, or object with __rich_console__ method is required
```

I tried inserting `console.width = 150` prior to panel creation though this did not make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you want side-by-side tables inside your panel, you'll need to wrap them in a [`Column`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/columns.html):

```
panel = Panel.fit(
    Columns([table1, table2]),
    title="My Panel",
    border_style="red",
    title_align="left",
    padding=(1, 2),
)

console.print(panel)
```

That results in:

```
╭─ My Panel ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                              │
│  ┏━━━┳━━━┓ ┏━━━┳━━━┓                                                         │
│  ┃ a ┃ b ┃ ┃ c ┃ d ┃                                                         │
│  ┡━━━╇━━━┩ ┡━━━╇━━━┩                                                         │
│  │ a │ b │ │ c │ d │                                                         │
│  │ a │ b │ │ c │ d │                                                         │
│  └───┴───┘ └───┴───┘                                                         │
│                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

You'll note that the panel is taking up the full terminal width despite the fact that we're calling `Panel.fit`. I haven't found a solution to that issue, but it is possible to provide `Panel` with an explicit width:

```
panel = Panel.fit(
    Columns([table1, table2]),
    width=40,
    title="My Panel",
    border_style="red",
    title_align="left",
    padding=(1, 2),
)
```

Which produces:

```
╭─ My Panel ───────────────────────────╮
│                                      │
│  ┏━━━┳━━━┓ ┏━━━┳━━━┓                 │
│  ┃ a ┃ b ┃ ┃ c ┃ d ┃                 │
│  ┡━━━╇━━━┩ ┡━━━╇━━━┩                 │
│  │ a │ b │ │ c │ d │                 │
│  │ a │ b │ │ c │ d │                 │
│  └───┴───┘ └───┴───┘                 │
│                                      │
╰──────────────────────────────────────╯
```